# How to copy cells based on a date (month = target sheet , day = target column)?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to solve a problem that I have on one excel file. The target is to import data from different excel files, compile the imported data and paste it to a target column, in target sheet based on a date.
E.g. the date is 19.01.2023, so the data should be copied to sheet 1, to the column U (assigned to 19).

[image: Sheet DCL127 example]

The data and the date are already imported, I just don't know how to write the code that the data will be copied from the sheet DCL127 to the right sheet and column.

Thanks in advance for any help!
May the Force be with you!

Comment: When you say it's copied to "sheet 1" do you mean the first sheet in the workbook, or the sheet with the tab name "Sheet1"?  How is column U assigned to the 19th day?  Is it just a case of remove 2 from the column number?  So day 1 will always be in column C and 31st is always in column AG?

Comment: Show us what you already have so we can work from there. First thing that comes to mind is using `MONTH(yourDateVariable)` and `DAY(yourDateVariable)`

Comment: Exactly,  I meant tab in the same Workbook (I crated 12 tabs, named 1,2,3,4...12 so for each month).  Starting from column C I have 31 columns for each day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

This snippet select the sheet (sh) named `Sheetx` where x is the month number from cell E2.

Assign the (day+2) column to col.  (for the sake to set 19 to column U. day1 will column C etc.)

The data range is C1:C5

The result will be in the selected column from row 2. (this can be set with col.Cells(y)

```
Sub copydatatonew()

Set sourcesh = Worksheets("DCL127")
Set datarng = sourcesh.Range("C1:C5")
Set sh = Worksheets("sheet" & sourcesh.Range("E2"))
Set col = sh.Columns(sourcesh.Range("F2") + 2)


datarng.Copy col.Cells(2)


End Sub
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT! our code helped a lot! I just edited it Sub Copy_DCL()

Set sourcesh = Worksheets("DCL127")
Set datarng = sourcesh.Range("C1:C5")
Set sh = Worksheets(sourcesh.Range("E2") + 1)
Set col = sh.Columns(sourcesh.Range("F2") + 2)


datarng.Copy

col.Cells(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub